# How to create a Google Map API Polyline map with labels

Tags: api, dictionary, polyline

I used the Google Map API Polyline example at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple to develop my map.

Now, I need to put about 8 characters of text at the destination end of each of the lines in my map indicating the name of the destination. Is there an easy way to do this? I would like to see someone just add text to the endpoint of the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st answer was a good start, but it put marker at each end of the line and I only wanted the final destination to have a marker with a label. It was also unclear how to place different text on each line.

I used the following code (adding Marker2, etc.: I posted an example at: https://www.qsomap.org/QSOmapProduction/polytest.htm

```
    var marker1= new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.999490,-87.400400),
    labelContent: "N9AAA",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
    labelClass: "labels",
    labelStyle: {opacity: 1.00},
    labelVisible: true,
    icon: '/images/red-dot.png',
    map: map,
    title: 'N9AAA'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: location,//{lat: xxx, lng: xxx}
   label: "88888888",//your text
   map: map//your map instance
});
```

Just do that to add text label.

I've made an example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-currying-k9m5n?fontsize=14)